# How to concatenate multiple videos with fades (from- and to-black) in-between?

Tags: ffmpeg, filter

I recently had the following problem:

I wanted, using ffmpeg, to **concatenate several videos** (with audio), **adding black clips** (with null audio) between them , and lastly **fade** the videos from those black clips (**fade-in**) and to those black clips (**fade-out**).

Schematically, with 2 videos for instance:

```
black (1s) --> part_1 (60s) --> black (3s) --> part_2 (120s) --> black (1s)
            ^                ^              ^                 ^
       (2s-fade-in)     (2s-fade-out)  (2s-fade-in)      (2s-fade-out)
```

I was looking for a **one-liner solution** (to avoid re-encoding original videos more than once), but only found documentation or help for each part of the problem.

Having figured it out, I wanted to document my solution for those after me who will stumble on a similar problem :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So here is what I came up with.

## A not *fully* one-liner solution

### 1) Generate black clips

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i "color=black:s=1920x1080:r=30" \
 -f lavfi -i "anullsrc=r=48000:cl=stereo" \
 -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -t 3 empty_3s.mp4
```

Use **lavfi filters** to generate your empty clip. Of course, change the parameters according to your videos and what you want to achieve. Especially:

- in first (video) source filter:

  - `s` (size) should match that of the videos you want to concatenate.
  - `r` (frame rate) should also match your videos (especially if your want a constant frame rate output)
- in second (audio) source filter:

  - `r` (sample rate) should match that of the audio tracks from the videos you want to concatenate.
  - `cl` (channel layout) should also match the audio from your videos

Output parameters (codecs for instance) should match those of your videos. Use `-t` to set the length (in seconds) of the empty clip.

### 2) Concatenate and fade your videos using a **complex filtergraph**

```
ffmpeg -i empty_1s.mp4 -i part_1.mp4 -i empty_3s.mp4 -i part_2.mp4 -i empty_1s.mp4 \
 -filter_complex \
  "[1:v] fade=t=in:st=0:d=2, fade=t=out:st=58:d=2 [1v]; \
   [1:a] afade=t=in:st=0:d=2, afade=t=out:st=58:d=2 [1a]; \
   [3:v] fade=t=in:st=0:d=2, fade=t=out:st=118:d=2 [3v]; \
   [3:a] afade=t=in:st=0:d=1, afade=t=out:st=118:d=2 [3a]; \
   [0:v] [0:a] [1v] [1a] [2:v] [2:a] [3v] [3a] [4:v] [4:a] concat=n=5:v=1:a=1 [v] [a]" \
 -map "[v]" -map "[a]" -c:v libx264 -c:a aac output.mp4
```

**Explanation:**

- we first specify the **inputs** (`-i`) that we will concatenate
- we then set a **complex filter** (`-filter_complex`), that we use to:

  - first, **fade in and out** our videos. To that end we use the **`fade`** (for video) and **`afade`** (for audio) filters. We specify the start (`st`) and duration (`d`) for each fade. We output the results with outpad names (`[1v]`, `[1a]`...).
  - then, **concatenate** the black clips and the previously faded videos, using the **`concat`** filter. We specify the number of input segments `n` (i.e. the number of video+audio sets, in our case 5) we want to concat, and the number of video (`v=1`) and audio (`a=1`) streams for the output.
- we `map` the final output to the output streams from the concat filter
- specify the encoding parameters to whatever you want :)

**Important notes:**

- your videos (inputs) must have the **same characteristics** (pixel and sample format for video, sample rate and channel layout for audio). See [concat documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#concat) for more info.
- in the fade filter, we specify start time and duration in seconds, but you can use frames or samples as well with `s` and `n` (video) or `ss` and `ns` (audio) options. See [afade](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#afade) and [fade](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#fade) filters documentation.
- you must know the duration of your videos for the fade filter, especially for fade-outs. See [this question](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/19867/how-to-fade-in-out-a-video-audio-clip-with-unknown-duration) for hints on how two fade-out clips without having to manually specify start time.

## True one-liner

If you really want a one-liner (and not having to encode empty black clips), you can use:

```
ffmpeg \
 -f lavfi -t 1 -i "color=black:s=1920x1080:r=30" -f lavfi -t 1 -i "anullsrc=r=48000:cl=2" \
 -i part_1.mp4 \
 -f lavfi -t 3 -i "color=black:s=1920x1080:r=30" -f lavfi -t 3 -i "anullsrc=r=48000:cl=2" \
 -i part_2.mp4 \
 -f lavfi -t 1 -i "color=black:s=1920x1080:r=30" -f lavfi -t 1 -i "anullsrc=r=48000:cl=2" \
 -filter_complex \
  "[0:v] null [0v]; [1:a] anull [0a]; [3:v] null [2v]; [4:a] anull [2a]; \
   [6:v] null [4v]; [7:a] anull [4a]; \
   [2:v] fade=t=in:st=0:d=2, fade=t=out:st=58:d=2 [1v]; \
   [2:a] afade=t=in:st=0:d=2, afade=t=out:st=58:d=2 [1a]; \
   [5:v] fade=t=in:st=0:d=1, fade=t=out:st=118:d=2 [3v]; \
   [5:a] afade=t=in:st=0:d=1, afade=t=out:st=118:d=2 [3a]; \
   [0v] [0a] [1v] [1a] [2v] [2a] [3v] [3a] [4v] [4a] concat=n=5:v=1:a=1 [v] [a]" \
 -map "[v]" -map "[a]" -c:v libx264 -c:a aac output.mp4
```

In that case we must **beware of the input indices**, as *black video clips and null audio clips are separated inputs* (I didn't figure out how to put them as two streams in a single input, if you have an idea feel free to share it).

Here I applied `null` and `anull` filters to those inputs to give them outpad tags, in order to use consistent identifiers in the `concat` filter. But this is purely optional.

Hope this helps, feel free to improve my solution with your insights :)

Comment: You don't need to generate distinct source filter inputs for the null video and audio segments. They can be used multiple times in the filter_complex.